# Unable to install runner for GitLab on my Windows

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I run gitlab-runner install in cmd(as admin) under directory C:\Program Files\GitLab-Runner,
It gives me following error :

```
C:\GitLab-Runner>gitlab-runner.exe install
time="2021-04-29T15:29:23+05:30" level=info msg="Did not set console mode for cl
i" error="The parameter is incorrect."
time="2021-04-29T15:29:23+05:30" level=info msg="Did not set console mode for cl
i" error="The parameter is incorrect."
Runtime platform                                  ←[0;m  arch←[0;m=amd64 os←[0;m
=windows pid←[0;m=2388 revision←[0;m=7f7a4bb0 version←[0;m=13.11.0
←[31;1mFATAL: Failed to install gitlab-runner: service gitlab-runner already exi
sts←[0;m
```

And one TOML file "config" is generated in the directory.
This is the message in TOML:-

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800
```

How can I configure runner on my windows for GitLab.
Need help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Your error says : `service gitlab-runner already exists`

try `gitlab-runner.exe uninstall` and then reinstall it